# Dump libx264 encoding parameters in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding, x264, libx264

Is it possible to get a list of parameter values used in libx264 while encoding a stream? I am using a ffmpeg binary to encode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to answer my own question:
Just check the the console output during encoding. `ffmpeg` will show libx264 parameters as a string.

For finished videos use `strings` command:

```
$ strings output.mkv | grep x264
```